# install mysql in Bonita Studio 7.12

Tags: mysql, tomcat, h2, bonita

I'm working with bonita studio 7.12 and I want to set bonita to work with mysql database without using mysql connector( by default bonita should use mysql not H2 database).haw can I configure it? and haw can I use tomcat bundle with mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Bonita Studio is a development environment and embeds an H2 database for its internal storage. This database **cannot be changed**.
However, it allows to connect to EXTERNAL systems like a MySQL database via connectors, if you want.

On a Tomcat bundle, however, you MUST choose a database different from H2, and MySQL is a good choice. Here's [how to configure it](https://documentation.bonitasoft.com/bonita/latest/tomcat-bundle#configuration).

Comment: I see this configuration and I followed it but I can't configure bonita to work with tomcat bundle and not with embed tomcat

Comment: So can you precise why you can't? What is the problem, the errors you get, the missing documentation?

Comment: I update the database.properties correctly,and I start the bundle but bonita still now work with the embed tomcat. and when I update the database.properties of the embed tomcat,bonita can't deploy any organisation or any business data...did you get the point?

Comment: When you say "embed tomcat", do you mean "embedded H2"?

Comment: Are you sure you:
* modified the file <INSTALL_DIR>/setup/database.properties ?
* started the Tomcat bundle using script start-bonita.sh ?

Actually, this is the script start-bonita.sh that calls the "setup tool" that configures the Tomcat bundle to use your MySQL database.
If you start Tomcat directly without this scripts, the bundle does not get configured, and the default H2 configuration is used.